# Issue while checking any date field with 08/09

Tags: bash, shell

I have below code to calculate the time difference in mm:ss format. However its not working if I have values like 08/09. I saw in few blobs by adding #10 it will resolve , however its not working out for me. can anyone please help .

```
#!/bin/bash
start_ts=04:24:07
stop_ts=04:24:09
ts_get_sec()
{
  read -r h m s <<< $(echo 10#$1 | tr ':' ' ' )
  echo $(((h*60*60)+(m*60)+s))
}
START=$(ts_get_sec $start_ts)
STOP=$(ts_get_sec $stop_ts)
DIFF=$((STOP-START))
echo "$((DIFF/60)):$((DIFF%60))"
```

Error I am getting:

> value too great for base (error token is "09")

Please suggest if syntactically I am correct or not.

Comment: Can you show the example with problems?  You should add `10#` inside `$(( ))` like change `$((h * 60))` into `$((10#$h *  60))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove leading blanks from h m, and s after the split:

```
ts_get_sec()
{
  read -r h m s <<< $(echo $1 | tr ':' ' ' )
  h=$((10#$h))
  m=$((10#$m))
  s=$((10#$s))  
  echo $(((h*60*60)+(m*60)+s*1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because 09 is great in octal base.

```
$(echo 10#$1 | tr ':' ' ')
```

will result in: `10#04 24 09`, so only 04 is considered a decimal number, while 09 is considered octal number.

Try this:

```
$(echo $1 | awk -F ":" '{ print "10#" $1 " 10#" $2 " 10#" $3; }' )
```

that is: `10#04 10#24 10#09` so every number is decimal number and it should fix the error.